# Change LookupEntry FullValue

Tags: c#, csom, lookup-tables

In a MS Projects LookupTables I would like to change the FullValue of an element but I get the following error:
Error CS0200 A value cannot be assigned to the property or indexer 'LookupEntry.FullValue' because it is read-only
Please can you help me how to do it?

```
var username = "****";
var password = "****";
var site = "https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/PWA";
var lutName = "zzSlkt";
var oldFullValue = "one";
var newFullValue = "new_one";
var description = "Description five";

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (var ch in password.ToCharArray())
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
}
ProjectContext context = new ProjectContext(site);
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);

context.Load(context.Web);
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine("   Connected to '" + context.Web.Title + "'");

context.Load(context.LookupTables, lts => lts.Include(lt => lt.Name, lt => lt.Entries, lt => lt.SortOrder));
context.ExecuteQuery();
var lookupTable = context.LookupTables.First(lt => lt.Name == lutName);

foreach (LookupEntry ItemToModify in lookupTable.Entries)
    if (ItemToModify.FullValue == oldFullValue)
    {
        ItemToModify.FullValue = newFullValue;
        ItemToModify.Description = description;
    }
context.LookupTables.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: What other properties/methods exist on the object

Comment: ItemToModify.AppAlternateId
ItemToModify.Context
ItemToModify.Description
ItemToModify.FullValue
ItemToModify.Id
ItemToModify.InternalName
ItemToModify.ServerObjectIsNull
ItemToModify.SortIndex
ItemToModify.Tag
ItemToModify.TypedObject
ItemToModify.TypedObject 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj193041(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: ItemToModify.DeleteObject
ItemToModify.Equals
ItemToModify.GetHashCode
ItemToModify.GetType
ItemToModify.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated
ItemToModify.IsPropertyAvailable
ItemToModify.RefreshLoad
ItemToModify.ToString